# Why pandas indexing a subset by location gives an error?

Tags: python, pandas

I was reading the book about Pandas by Wes Mckinney and stumbled upon this example.

```
people = DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 5),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                   index=['Joe', 'Steve', 'Wes', 'Jim', 'Travis'])
```

If we want to modify the dataframe in place we have to run the following command

```
people.loc[2:3, ['b', 'c']] = np.nan
```

based on label-indexing and avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning. The command works perfectly and the dataframe is changed accordingly.
My question is, why if I run the code below (same code as above but without assigning a value to the subset) I get an indexing error? I understand *.loc* is label indexing and we should not use 2:3, but why don't I get an error also when assigning a value?

```
people.loc[2:3, ['b', 'c']]
```

Result:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [2] of <class 'int'>
```

Comment: "2" and "3" are not in your index... your index is `['Joe', 'Steve', 'Wes', 'Jim', 'Travis']`. You'd need to do `people.loc[['Wes', 'Jim'], ['b', 'c']]` for example IIUC

Comment: Agree, "2" and "3" are not my indexes, but why assigning a value for it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a change of mindset. If you are familiar with list / ndarray in Python, you know that when you do this assignment:

```
array[42] = 10
```

...index 42 must exist or you will get an `IndexError`.

Pandas flips the convention to "if does not assist, create it". So when you assign somethings, pandas will either change the location or create a new one:

```
people['age'] = ...               # create a new column called `age`
people.loc[2:3, ['b', 'c']] = ... # create rows with labels 2 and 3 and assign
                                  # some values for column `b` and `c`
```

If values already exist in those locations, they will be modified.

The "get" operation still works as before: you cannot retrieve what is not there :

```
people['gender']    # KeyError. Column `gender` does not exist
people.loc[5]       # TypeError. Can't find row with label 5 in the index
```

Comment: I'm not certain that's what's going on here... if you look at the result of ``people.loc[2:3, ['b', 'c']] = np.nan`` it is not creating new rows, but modifying existing rows.

Comment: If exists, it will modify. If not, it will create

Comment: ...that's true for an integer, but demonstrably untrue for a slice, as in the original question. e.g. ``people.loc[20:21, 'a'] = 100`` does not add any new rows.

Answer (score 1):

The operative answer is that assignment via square brackets is implemented in `__setitem__` and extracting data via square brackets is implemented in `__getitem__`, which are different code paths. The behavior you found is probably unintentional.

I suspect the issue comes from the fact that `loc[]` and `iloc[]` were created to replace [`ix[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html), which explicitly allowed mixing of indices by integer position (as in `iloc[]`) and by index value (as in `loc[]`), and this behavior is a corner case that reveals a vestige of the earlier API.

I would suggest not relying on it, as it is undocumented, probably unintentional, and likely subject to change in future releases.